# How can I install Wine (i386) on Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, playonlinux, 19.10

Since Canonical decided not to include i386 packages support and I get errors during Playonlinux / Crossover / wine installations, what is a workaround to address this issue?

It's a known issue, and I'm asking if someone solved it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Execute the following commands for a Wine installation:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
wget -qO - https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ disco main'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Comment: Does `winehq-stable` include `i386` architecture or you have to force it with `winehq-stable:i386`?

Comment: here, i386 version of WINE is installed. WINE x64 is only installed (i guess) using `sudo apt install wine64`